# How to change template page in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have created tamplate page, I have checked it as an allowed template in my document type and I'm still getting error:

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/New.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a template directly at its URL. Templates are used by documents (content) to render that specific document in a particular way.

So you would need to create a document from the document type and then access it at the URL that this document is given. Then it will render the page - using the template you have selected.